# Limiting the length of Long Text fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I use Access to validate fixed record length files which works well. I used Saved Imports to load a file and then validate that I have the correct number of fields, formatting, etc. I just encountered a file that has a field with a length of 256.  256 will not work with the Short Text data type.  I haven't found a way to limit a Long Text length to 256.  Is that possible and how would I do it if it is?

Answer (score 1):

> [Is it possible to] limit a Long Text length to 256?

No. Long Text (previously called "Memo") fields do not have a user-defined maximum length. If you want to impose a limit on their contents then your import code would have to truncate any overly long entries.